# Kivy widget's opacity doesn't update visually

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I want to hide one widget and show another on button's click. I do it by changing opacity form 1 to 0 and from 0 to 1. The firt widget becomes invisible, but the second is not showing.
This is my python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty


from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1920')

Config.set('graphics', 'height', '1080')
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 1)



class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class PasswordEntryWidget(BoxLayout):
    def checkPswd(instance, pswd):
        if (pswd == "123"):
            instance.parent.opacity = 0
            instance.parent.disabled = True
            instance.parent.parent.ids.settingsWgt.opacity = 1.0
            #print(instance.parent.parent.ids.settingsWgt.size_hint)

class SettingsEntryWidget(BoxLayout):
    def checkPswd(instance, pswd):
        if (pswd == "123"):
            print ("It's OK!")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

This is my.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.11.1
#:include loginWidgets.kv
<MyScreenManager>:
    FirstScreen:
    SecondScreen:

<FirstScreen>:
    name: "FirstScreen"
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'img/background.png'

    FloatLayout:
        size: root.size
        PasswordEntryWidget:
            id: passwordWgt
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
            pos_hint: {'top': 0.35, 'right': 0.7}
        SettingsEntryWidget:
            id: settingsWgt 
            opacity: 0
            disabled: True
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.32
            pos_hint: {'top': 0.35, 'right': 0.95}



<SecondScreen>:
    name: "SecondScreen"
    Label:
        color: 1,1,1,1
        font_size: 10
        center_x: root.width/4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "Lalalala"
```

And this is loginWidgets.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

<PasswordEntryWidget>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: 20
    #padding: 50
    TextInput:
        id: adminPswdLine
        multiline: False
        password: True
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 30
        font_size: self.height - 10
    Button:
        id: "takeAdminPswd"
        size_hint_x: 0.5
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
        on_press: root.checkPswd(adminPswdLine.text)

<SettingsEntryWidget>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: 20
    #padding: 50
    TextInput:
        id: host
        padding: [5, 2, 0, 5]
        text: ""
        multiline: False
        password: False
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 30
        font_size: self.height - 10
    Button:
        id: "takeSettings"
        size_hint_x: 0.5
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
        on_press: root.checkPswd(adminPswdLine.text)
```

As I said, the first part works well. PasswordWgt hide perfectly, but SettingsWgt doesn't become visible. When I print it's opacity after - it gives 1, so widget must be visible, but it's not. I checked ids and what elements are there and needed widget is there with this id.
Is it a bug or I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your are changing the opacity of the  container (`FloatLayout`) instead of the `PasswordEntryWidget`. Just change:

```
class PasswordEntryWidget(BoxLayout):
    def checkPswd(instance, pswd):
        if (pswd == "123"):
            instance.parent.opacity = 0
            instance.parent.disabled = True
            instance.parent.parent.ids.settingsWgt.opacity = 1.0
```

to:

```
class PasswordEntryWidget(BoxLayout):
    def checkPswd(instance, pswd):
        if (pswd == "123"):
            instance.opacity = 0
            instance.disabled = True
            instance.parent.parent.ids.settingsWgt.opacity = 1.0
```

and I think it will work as you desire.

Comment: The first widget becomes invisible, so `instance.parent.opacity = 0` works like I need. The problem is somewhere here: ` instance.parent.parent.ids.settingsWgt.opacity = 1.0` , but there is widget with such id in `instance.parent.parent.ids`

Comment: But making the entire container opacity = 0 means that it doesn't matter what you set the opacity for the `SettingsEntryWidget` to, because its container (parent) has opacity = 0. If a container opacity is zero, none of its children will appear. Please try my answer.

Comment: Hmmm...That's have a sense...And this works! Oh god, but what is `instance` then? Is it the button? Then why button.opacity changes opacity of all widget? Or is it the widget? But why so? And why instance.parent.parent have settingsWgt in ids then?

Comment: The `'instance` in your `checkPswd()` method is normally named `self` (but that is not required), and its value is the `PasswordEntryWidget` instance. The `parent.parent` of the `PasswordEntryWidget` is the `FirstScreen` instance (which contains the 'ids` dictionary).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful.